# Airflow logs copied to GCS but not reflecting in Airflow UI

Tags: airflow

I have deployed the latest airflow using helm and I have configured the logs to be pushed to GCS. I can see that logs are being pushed to GCS bucket however Airflow UI is not reflecting them.
This is what I see in UI logs

`*** No logs found in GCS; ti=%s <TaskInstance: xyz> *** Could not read served logs: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

My values.yaml for GCS configuration looks like below

```
# Airflow scheduler settings
scheduler:
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: google-cloud-key
      mountPath: /opt/airflow/secrets
  extraVolumes:
    - name: google-cloud-key
      secret:
        secretName: sc-key

# Airflow webserver settings
webserver:
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: google-cloud-key
      mountPath: /opt/airflow/secrets
  extraVolumes:
    - name: google-cloud-key
      secret:
        secretName: sc-key

workers:
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: google-cloud-key
      mountPath: /opt/airflow/secrets
  extraVolumes:
    - name: google-cloud-key
      secret:
        secretName: sc-key

# Airflow triggerer settings
triggerer:
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: google-cloud-key
      mountPath: /opt/airflow/secrets
  extraVolumes:
    - name: google-cloud-key
      secret:
        secretName: sc-key

config:
  logging:
    remote_logging: 'True'
    remote_base_log_folder: 'gs://airflow-bucket/logs/'
    remote_log_conn_id: 'sc-key'
    google_key_path:  "/opt/airflow/secrets/key.json"

connections:
  - id: sc-key
    type: google_cloud_platform
    description: my GCP connection
        extra: |
      {
        "extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path": "/opt/airflow/secrets/key.json",
        "extra__google_cloud_platform__num_retries": 5
      }
env:
  - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
    value: "/opt/airflow/secrets/key.json"
  - name: AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_LOGGING
    value: "True"
  - name: AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_LOG_CONN_ID
    value: "sc-key"
  - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER
    value: "gs://airflow-bucket/logs/"
  - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__GOOGLE_KEY_PATH
    value: "opt/airflow/secrets/key.json"

extraPipPackages:
  - apache-airflow[google]
```

Can someone please help me with what I am missing here?
Thanks

Comment: I feel that I am doing something wrong with 'connections:', though I have created it in UI manually as well, but still doesn't work.